# syntax error,unexpected T_else online 81

Tags: php, apache

i am try to build a contact form using html and php but im getting this a message parse error:,syntax error,unexpected T_ELSE in c:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\form_process.php on line 81,i really do not know where im doing it wrong,this is my code below

```
<?php

    session_start();

      if($_POST['submit'])
      {
       $num = 0;

       if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 0)
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_name']);
      }
      else 
      {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_name'] = "You have not filled out a Name";

      }

       if(strlen($_POST['surname']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['surname'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_surname']);
      }

      else 
      {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_surname'] = "You have not filled out a Surname";

      }

       if(strlen($_POST['phone']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_phone']);
      }
      else 
      {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_phone'] = "You have not filled out a Phone Number";

      }

       if(strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_email']);
      }
      else 
      {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_email'] = "You have not filled out a Email Address";

      }

       if(strlen($_POST['comments']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['comments'] = $_POST['comments'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_comments']);
      }
      else 
      {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_comments'] = "You have not filled out a Comment";

      }

         if ($num == 0)
          {
            //process form
             echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
            header("Location: inter.php");      
            }


     else{

       header("location: inter.php");
      }

    ?>
```

somebody help

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you will see this kind of mistake instantly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom of your code there is an unclosed if statement. Check in your code.

```
if{  

...

}else{
    header("location: inter.php");
}
```

Comment: thanks alot,but im getting another error the form is not working according to the way its supposed to,if i click submit button it redirects me to the home page and if i go back to the contacts thats when its showing that i did not enter the anything if i click the resert button its not doing anything

Comment: This is a different question. If you're not still getting same error, please accept one of the answers and ask an other one for your question. I can't really answer your question because I don't know about your code which handles your form.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else { header("location: inter.php"); }` isn't balanced with anything else :)

You should definitely use consistent indentation and place your curly braces consistently.

Here's an update, with the (missing?) curly braces:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_POST['submit']) {
    $num = 0;

    if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 0) {
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_name']);
    }
    else {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_name'] = "You have not filled out a Name";

    }

    if(strlen($_POST['surname']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['surname'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_surname']);
    }
    else {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_surname'] = "You have not filled out a Surname";

    }

    if(strlen($_POST['phone']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_phone']);
    }
    else {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_phone'] = "You have not filled out a Phone Number";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_email']);
    }
    else {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_email'] = "You have not filled out a Email Address";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['comments']) > 0){
        $num = $num;
         $_SESSION['comments'] = $_POST['comments'];
         unset($_SESSION['error_comments']);
    }
    else {
       $num = $num + 1;
       $_SESSION['error_comments'] = "You have not filled out a Comment";
      }

    if ($num == 0) {
            //process form
             echo "success";
    }
    else {
            header("Location: inter.php");      
    }
  }
  else {
       header("location: inter.php");
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a parenthesis

```
        header("Location: inter.php");      
    }

} // This one is missing
else {
```

Answer (score 0):

I this you're missing an opening brace on the line `if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 0)`, and it should start:

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $num = 0;

    if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 0) 
    { // added a brace here
        $num = $num;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        unset($_SESSION['error_name']);
    }
    else
```

You can find things like this more easily by making sure your code is laid out methodically, or by using an editor that shows matching braces.

Comment: thanks alot,but im getting another error the form is not working according to the way its supposed to,if i click submit button it redirects me to the home page and if i go back to the contacts thats when its showing that i did not enter the anything if i click the resert button its not doing anything

Comment: Maybe your form isn't being submitted by POST (`method="post"`), or you're not submitting a value for `$_POST['submit']` (`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`).

Comment: im using the same method is it ok if you can give me you email address so that i send u the whole if u do not mind?my email is elgin19@gmail.com im kind of new with php and im try to build a simple site

Answer (score 0):

> There's 2 else of same if

```
if ($num == 0)
          {
            //process form
             echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
            header("Location: inter.php");      
            }


     else{

       header("location: inter.php");
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: thanks alot,but im getting another error the form is not working according to the way its supposed to,if i click submit button it redirects me to the home page and if i go back to the contacts thats when its showing that i did not enter the anything if i click the resert button its not doing anything